# ARP broadcasts even when found in local cache

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, arp

I have few win2012 servers that I just discovered ARP broadcasts are being generated even though the entries are found in it's local arp cache. My understanding is that if it's already on the servers arp cache it should not have to send an arp broadcast. Any reasons why this would occur?

Comment: How did you determine that the entries were already in the ARP cache at the time of the ARP activity rather than as a result of the ARP activity?

Comment: I used arp -a to display my cache entries while I had wireshark running as the arp request were made.